# Remover classe ao redimensionar

Tags: jquery, css

Eu criei um menu que, dependendo do tamanho da tela, se comporta como um menu fixo. Porém, ao redimensionar a tela pro tamanho normal, o menu continua adicionando a classe pra fixá-lo, quando não era pra acontecer.

Esse é o menu (que fica dentro de uma sidebar):

```
.bottom{
    bottom: 90px;
    padding: 15px;
    height: 45px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px #f5f5f5;
}
```

Essa é a classe usada pra definir ele como fixo:

```
.glue{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9;
    top: 0;
}
```

Esse é o código que eu usei pra fixar dependendo do tamanho da tela. Para telas menores do que 1024px, ele fica fixo depois de rolar 410px e para telas maiores que 1024px e menores ou iguais a 1125px, depois de 500px.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var ww = $(window).width();
    if (ww <= 1024) {
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scroll >= 410) {
                $('.bottom').addClass("glue");

            } else {
                $('.bottom').removeClass("glue");
            }
        });
    } if ((ww > 1024) && (ww <= 1125)) {
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scroll >= 500) {
                $('.bottom').addClass("glue");

            } else {
                $('.bottom').removeClass("glue");
            }
        });
    }
 });
```

Eu reproduzi esse problema em um [blog separado](https://tsttestets.tumblr.com/), já que não consegui pelo editor daqui

Comment: Não seria melhor utilizar media queries ?

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você está aninhando eventos, o que geralmente não se deve fazer. Por quê? Porque quando você chamar um irá acumular na memória o outro.

O que você deve fazer é usar os dois eventos ao mesmo tempo, o de `scroll` e o de `resize` utilizando o método `.on()`. Inseri também o evento `load`, que irá fazer a mesma coisa se o usuário der um refresh na página com o scroll rolado.

E ainda dá pra melhorar o código atribuindo o `$(this)` (que referencia o elemento do evento) a uma variável e usar outra variável (usei `acao`) para controlar quando deve inserir e retirar a classe `.glue`:

```js
$(window).on("load resize scroll", function(){
   var acao;
   var $t = $(this);
   var ww = $t.width();
   var scroll = $t.scrollTop();
   
   $("#testescroll").text(scroll); // linha de teste. Remova.
   
   if (
      (ww <= 1024 && scroll < 410)
      ||
      (ww > 1024 && ww <= 1125 && scroll < 500)
   ) {
      acao = true;
   }
   
   $('.bottom')[acao ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']("glue");
   
});
```

```css
/* TRECHO PARA TESTE */
#testescroll{
   position: fixed;
   top: 5px;
   right: 5px;
   background: red;
   color: white;
}

.box{
   height: 2000px;
}
/* REMOVA DAQUI PRA CIMA*/

.glue{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9;
    top: 0;
}

.bottom{
    bottom: 90px;
    padding: 15px;
    height: 45px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="testescroll"></span>
<div class="box">box</div>
<div class="bottom">bottom</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vou dar um exemplo alternativo para a pergunta, utilizando **media queries** (CSS) ao invés de **JavaScript**. Ficando a cargo do usuário utilizar ou não.

```html
<style>

  /* Para telas até 1024px */  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  
    /* Seu bloco de código CSS aqui */
    
  }
  
  
  /* Para telas de 1025px até 1125px */  
  @media only screen and (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1125px) {
  
    /* Seu bloco de código CSS aqui */
  }
  
</style>
```

- Se quiser mais referências sobre como utilizar media queries, é só acessar esse link [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries).

Comment: Olá Jason, obrigada pela sua atenção. Esqueci de adicionar a minha pergunta o meu código de media querie, pois estou utilizando um também. Só ele já seria suficiente mesmo, mas o problema é que eu quero que o menu fique fixo apenas depois de rolar certos pixels pra baixo, e eu não conseguiria chegar a esse resultado só utilizando o  CSS :/